# Distribute rsync over multiple network interfaces

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to transfer one large file over two slow network connections to save time.

One idea is to split file, rsync the parts to the server and concat them there. So, with a 1GB file

```
split -b 500m file 
rsync --address <eth0> file.000 server:~/ & \
rsync --address <eth1> file.001 server:~/
ssh server cat file.001 >> file.000; mv file.000 file
// run rsync on the complete file again to make sure it worked
rsync file server:~/
```

Looks pretty kludgey to me. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What I did once:

Implement 2 VPNs or IP Tunnels over each link and use the Linux bonding capabilities to glue them together. I did it with OpenVPN, via UDP and extremely fast encryption. You will not need 2 rsyncs this way, you will get a faster, single one.

To speed it up, use very powerful compression and a protocol with less overhead than SSH, maybe some UDP alternative to rsync (just Google for it).

Comment: I looked into this as well, but couldn't find anything for OS X on the client side.

Comment: You should be able to use Link Aggregate from OSX.

Comment: Could you please point me to a howto? Thanks.